# How do you say "Everyone in my family is Chinese" in Japanese?

Tags: translation, phrases, english-to-japanese

Please write the phrase in hiragana or romaji. All answers are appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

It's 私の家族は みんな 中国人 だ/です or so. みんな is an adverb here. When 私 is already a topic, it's usually omitted i.e. （私は）家族はみんな中国人です.